# ZeroDivisionError using range

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep getting a `ZeroDivisionError`. My code is below. What seems to be my problem?

```
def number(x):
    for i in range(x):
        if x%i == 0:
            print(i)
```

Comment: range(x) -> [0,1,2,...,x-1]

Comment: You don't have a syntax error. You have a *runtime* error.

Comment: Your problem is that you're dividing by zero....

Comment: You're trying to get the remainder after dividing by 0. Since division by 0 is not allowed, neither is this.

Answer (score 6):

You can start iterating at 1 instead of at 0:

```
def number(x):
    for i in range(1, x):
        if x % i == 0:
            print(i)
```